# Why does it take more time for molecules to diffuse in 2D than in 3D?

Tags: diffusion, brownian-motion

The formula to calculate the time for molecules to travel over a distance of `r` units, `r` being the Euclidean distance, is given by $t = \frac{r^2}{4D}$ for a 2D environment, and $t = \frac{r^2}{6D}$ for a 3D environment ($D$ is the diffusion coefficient. Not to be confused with D in 2D and 3D which stands for dimension).
From these two formulae, we can easily observe that for the same `r`, `t` will be larger in 2D than in 3D. Why? This seems a little confusing since `r` is the same. Is there a proper explanation for this observation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does $D$ represent?

Comment: @Flo $D$ in the denominator is the diffusion coefficient

Comment: This is not a biology question. The simple answer to your question is that, with an additional dimension, the particle will have a higher degree of freedom i.e. it is more unconstrained. For more details look at the equations for Brownian motion (check mean displacement). I am migrating this to [physics.se].

Comment: @WYSIWYG Thank you guiding the question to the proper forum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As WYSIWYG pointed out in a comment, it comes from the fact that the particule has more degrees of freedom in 3D than in 2D.

If you consider a free particle, all its space degrees of freedom are independent, which means that its motion along the $x$-axis is not affected by its motion about the $y$-axis. The diffusion equation for the density of particles $n$ is

$D \Delta n = \frac{\partial n}{\partial t}$,

where $\Delta = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}$ in 2D, and $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}$ in 3D. A simple dimensional analysis of this equation shows that the mean squared displacement along any of the axes $x$, $y$ or $z$ is given by

$<q^2> = D t$,

where $q$ stands for $x$, $y$ or $z$.

In 2D, the mean squared displacement is

$r^2 = <x^2> + <y^2> = 2 D t$

While in 3D, you get

$r^2 = <x^2> + <y^2> + <z^2> = 3 D t$.

Your result has a factor of $2$ more which comes from the fact that you can consider the radius of diffusion instead of the diameter of diffusion.

Comment: Thank you so much for the beautiful explanation. That cleared a lot of doubts.